# find the number of separated pairs in array

Tags: python, numpy

Good Morning,
I have a numpy array like:
    `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

and I would like to find the number of separated pairs of 1.

Three (or more) consecutive 1s count also as pair, i.e.: in this example the returned number should be 3.

What is the best technique to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),

`k` hold the unique key 0/1 based list lst below, `g` hold the correspond group iterator for the unique key `k`

```
import itertools
target = 1
lst = [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
pair_count = 0

for k,g in itertools.groupby(lst):
    if k==target and len(list(g))>1: # match target and more than 1 count as pair
        pair_count += 1
# pair_count = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement it yourself, see my code below:

```
l = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
# Create flag to skip all elements that have >2 1 in sequence
added = False
pairs_counter = 0 
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    rem = l[i - 1]
    if l[i] == 1 and rem == 1 and not added:
        added = True
        pairs_counter +=1
    if l[i] == 0:
        added = False
print (pairs_counter)
```

Complexity of this method is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
a = [0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
sum([
   a[i-2] == a[i-1] == 1 and a[i] == 0
   for i in xrange(2,len(a))
]) + (len(a) > 2 and a[-1] == a[-2] == 1)
```

It just keeps adding `True`s and `False`s together. I guess some people will find it ugly, I think it is OK.

It should be noted though, that if the list is really large, this is not a good option, since it creates the list of bools in memory. It would be easy to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools.groupby and sum

```
sum(1 for target, group_count in itertools.groupby(lst) 
    if target == 1 and len(list(group_count)) >= 2)
```